# Menu item for each module, with module content loading dynamically with Prism or MEF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism, mef

I am developing an application currently using Prism and MEF.

I would ideally like to generate a toolbar or menu with an item for each module, and when an item is clicked, only the views declared within that module load into a tab control.

For example:

Menu Region:
ModuleA(Selected) | ModuleB

Tab Region:
ModuleAViewA | ModuleAViewB | ModuleAViewC

Changes to
Menu Region:
Employees | Inventory(selected)

Tab Region:
Items | In Fi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a lot of questions similar to this on here.  In general, the approach you'll take is to define a service in an infrastructure DLL that your modules can reference.  Your modules will add menu / toolbar / ribbon item / whatever objects through the service.  Where the service is implemented is up to you - it can be in the Shell project, the infrastructure, or in a seperate module.  Obviously, if its in a seperate module, you'll have to make sure that your other modules define it as a dependency.

You may want to check out the following:

This one has a link to a project demonstrating a dynamic menu: 
[Looking for Prism example of Modules loading themselves into a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152282/looking-for-prism-example-of-modules-loading-themselves-into-a-menu)

In which I ask a question on how to build a dynamic menu:
[How to dynamically add MenuItems (with a header) to a WPF menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723580/how-to-dynamically-add-menuitems-with-a-header-to-a-wpf-menu)

More....
[Load Module Default Views In Region to Create Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325809/load-module-default-views-in-region-to-create-menu)

And more!
[Menu service in Prism application CAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516164/menu-service-in-prism-application-cal)

You can find more than this as well out there.  This has been a fairly common request; I'm sure you can piece together a good approach for doing this from the code samples out there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I did some searching, but hadn't found anything concise.